# Weird problems, like Software center and chromium dissappeared ... --fix-missing didn't help

Tags: apt, software-installation, software-center

I'm having some issues with my ubuntu installation.
I've got the last package installed not so long ago, but when I try to get into settings to see the exact version, I can't. It just won't open up.

I've got sublime installed, and when I click on it, I cannot access it. It's like I do not click on it at all.

Other stuff does work, so it's not a problem with the mouse or an impossibility to click...

Google Chromium has dissappeared, and so did the Software Center...

I've tried:

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Without any result...

Is there any way to try to get it sorted without having to reinstall the whole ubuntu again?

My laptop is an Asus K501U and I've been using Ubuntu for a long time before this weird behaviour...

Thanks for your insight, and sorry for the lack of information.